# FK to IK controller Shifting

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

I am facing an issue to shift hand/ leg of the character from FK to IK. This character is originally controlled by FK controller and now I wish to shift its control from FK to IK controllers. I have done necessary changes in N-Panel, as per my understanding and as indicated in the screenshots.  However, hands/ legs could not be shifted from FK settings to IK settings. Please help.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this Rigify?  Not everybody uses rigify; I'm temporarily adding that as a tag, and would recommend adding it to the question if that's part of the issue.  Other than that, I don't see any bones that are disagreeing with your IK in the image.  Perhaps you could upload a file or a different image?

Comment: Yes you are right, this is rigify and please see that the left hand is getting controlled by FK bones, instead of the settings at N Panels are done for IK bones. As suggested the google drive link for the blend file is mentioned below. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y34Mmbfj4RhEgJwwP2txf9varD0qLxAk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't recreate your problem.  Your left hand is being controlled by IK when I set the slider to 0.0, when I try it, and by FK when I set the slider to 1.0.  I'm using Blender 3.3.0.

Comment: Works for me as well: https://i.imgur.com/zaxVqYO.gif